# In swf AS3, how do you extract string content from a website

Tags: actionscript-3, url, flash

In swf AS3, how do you extract string content from a website?

In a html web page, they display a single line of text. In the swf, I want to use as3 to access that page by its URL and retrieve that line. Is the a way to access the content?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You simply load the file and read it. Say you have this HTML located at domain.com/test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="target">Get this text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You would load it in using a `URLLoader` in Flash:

```
var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
l.load(new URLRequest("domain.com/test"));
```

That will load the above HTML in as a `String` in the `completeHandler` via `Event.target.data`. You can then do two things: Search for your string via RegEx or search for it by setting the HTML as an `XML` object.

Using RegEx, you would do it like this:

```
function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    var s:String = e.target.data;
    var targets:Array = s.match(/(?<=<div class="target">).*(?=<\/div>)/igm);
}
```

`targets` would be an array of matches for a div with class name "target".

`XML` would be a bit more difficult, but infinitely more flexible and easy to maintain (in my opinion, at least). I won't give an example for how to do that, since parsing XML is a very common thing in AS3 and there are tons of other questions out there about it.

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Ok, using RegEx makes a lot of sense but how does it compile in Professional Flash when s:String has to look for the specific div from a html web?

Comment: I showed you how. `e.target.data` IS the HTML that you pulled from the web with my second code block. All HTML is is a String. Nothing more. You use RegEx to extract patterns from that String. If you're asking how to include the file in the compiled SWF, then you need to save the page to an HTML file and load it using an `Embed`.

Comment: I understand that e.target.data is the html, however when I compile the swf file and move it to a folder under htdocs with the index.html in it that refers to the swf file. Then access the html page from the browser, the swf that shows up has everything appearing except for that string (is suppose to appear in a textfield) that I want from another html page.

Comment: Are you successfully loading the file? Add an `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` handler and check. My guess is you have the URL wrong. I tested what I posted in my answer and it works fine. =\

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I think it might have to do with the fact that I used `var targets:Array = s.match(/(?<=<body>).*(?=<\/body>)/igm);` to get the body (that's what I want) but the targets[0] is just null.

Comment: I didn't test this in AS3, but it works on PHP and JS. Basically, `.*` matches all characters, except newlines. You'll need to add an `s` modifier to your pattern. `/(?<=<body>).*(?=<\/body>)/igms`, which forces `.` to match newline characters as well.